# My cold water valve Seems to have a cap. Is this normal and how can I remove it?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

I’m in the process of connecting my washing machine but noticed that my cold water supply valve seems to have a cap on it. My hot water one doesn’t. Is this normal? How can I remove this, it doesn’t budge when I try to turn it. [image]

Comment: Maybe the hot water valve had one too and it fell off.  It looks like it's just for comfort.

Comment: Looks like a dust cover or maybe it had a drip so they used the cap to seal it off.

Comment: It does not look like a washing machine valve and it appears to be under a cabinet.

Answer (score 3):

It has ridges on it so try twisting it counterclockwise with some adjustable pliers or channellocks.

Comment: Yep  - it's just frozen w/ crud.   But -- do be sure the valve itself is closed before removing!